# I can not delete entity from DB, JPA

Tags: java, spring, database, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

// After this operation my product entity has product name packaging, and department null and i still can not delete this from DB, what im trying to do in this deleteProduct metod is removing dependence between product and things and after this deleting from DB product

```
 @Transactional
    public void deleteProduct(Product product){
        
        departmentRepository.findById(product.getDepartment().getId()).ifPresent(
                department -> {
                    department.getProducts().remove(product);
                    product.setDepartment(null);
                    departmentRepository.save(department);
                }
        );
        
        productNameRepository.findById(product.getProductName().getId()).ifPresent(
                productName -> {
                    productName.getProducts().remove(product);
                    product.setProductName(null);
                    productNameRepository.save(productName);
                }
        );
        
        packagingRepository.findById(product.getPackaging().getId()).ifPresent(
                packaging -> {
                    packaging.getProducts().remove(product);
                    product.setPackaging(null);
                    packagingRepository.save(packaging);
                }
        );
        productRepository.save(product); 
        productRepository.deleteById(product.getId()); 
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }
```

HERE ARE MY ENTITIES

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Data
public class Product {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_sequence", sequenceName = "product_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "product_sequence")
    @Column(name = "product_id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_name_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "product_name_fk"))
    private ProductName productName;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "pacgaging_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "packaging_fk"))
    private Packaging packaging;

    @Column(name = "waga_netto")
    private Double netWeight;

    @Column(name = "waga_brutto")
    private Double grossWeight;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                    name = "product_departament_fk"))
    private Department department;

}
```

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "packaging")
public class Packaging {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "packaging_sequence", sequenceName = "packaging_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "packaging_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "nazwa_opakowania", nullable = false)
    String name;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "packaging", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Product> products = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "department")
@Data
public class Department {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "department_sequence", sequenceName = "department_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "department_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "nazwa_magazynu", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Product> products = new LinkedList<>();

    public void addProduct(Product product){
        products.add(product);
    }
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "product_name")
@Data
public class ProductName {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_name_sequece", sequenceName = "product_name_sequece", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_name_sequece")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    Long id;


    String name;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "productName",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )

    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Product> products = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

i tryed flush, looking for similiar problem at stackoverflow

Comment: Just delete the product. You are making it overly complex. Just do `productRepository.delete(product)`.